# Retarded Functional Differential Equation

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I would like some help understanding the proof of lemma 6.1 given [here](http://books.google.it/books?id=ZNLjAJQMhqwC&lpg=PA89&dq=hale%20%22locally%20completely%20continuous%22&pg=PA89#v=onepage&q=hale%20%22locally%20completely%20continuous%22&f=false), for the case of an **autonomous** Retarded Functional Differential Equation (RFDE).

The problem for the autonomous case (In the proof of the book, drop the dependence on $t$ in the first component and suppose $\sigma=0$) is as follows.

**Background:**

Suppose $r$ is fixed. Let $C=C([-r,0],\mathbb{R})$.

An autonomous RFDE is a differential equation of the form $$x'(t)=f(x_t)$$ where $x_t \in C$ defined by $x_t(\theta)=x(t+\theta)$ for $\theta \in [-r,0]$.

$f$ is a continuous function from $C$ to $\mathbb R$.

Given an initial function $\phi \in C$ suppose there exists a function $x \in C[-r,A)$ such that $x_0=\phi$ and $x$ satisfies the RFDE given above. Then $x$ is called a solution of the RFDE with initial function $\phi$.

In such a case when there is a unique solution of the RFDE, define the solution map $T_t:C\to C$ by $T_t(\phi)=x_t$, where $x$ is the solution of the RFDE with initial function $\phi$.

**Question**

Show that $T_t$ is locally completely continuous. That is for every $\phi \in C$ there is a neighbourhood $V_t$ of $\phi$ such that $T_t(V_t)$ is contained in a compact set of $C$.

What I don't understand in the proof is how they conclude that there is a nbd $V_t$ of $\phi$ and a constant $M$ such that $|T_\tau V_t|_C \leq M$ and $|f(T_\tau V_t)|<M$ **for all $0 \leq \tau \leq t$**?

How does one get such $V_t$ and $M$ that is uniform for all $0 \leq \tau \leq t$.

If someone with some experience in this area reads the question, I would appreciate it if you can suggest me some references to learn about Autonomous RFDE's.

Comment: Is "retarded" politically correct? You dont want to upset a differential equation. Believe me.

Comment: :) I didn't name these equations.

Comment: Differently-abled function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I retyped the argument making the simplifications indicated in the OP.

**Lemma 6.1** For any $t\ge r$, the map $T_t$ is locally completely continuous; that is, for any $t\ge r$, $\phi\in C$, there is a neighborhood $V_t$ of $\phi$ such that $T_t(V_t)$ is contained in a compact subset of $C$.

*Proof*. Since $f$ is continuous and $T_\tau\psi$ is jointly continuous in $\tau,\psi$, for any $t\ge 0  $ there is a neighborhood  $V_t$  of $\phi$ and a constant $M$ such that $|T_\tau (V_t)|\le M$, $|f(T_t(V_t))|\le M$ for $0\le \tau\le t$. Thus $|\dot x(V_t(\tau))|\le M$ for $0\le \tau\le t$. This implies the family of functions $\{x_t(\psi):\psi\in V_t\}$ is precompact for $t\ge r$. $\Box$

---

This is how I understand the above. Since $T$ is jointly continuous in $\tau$ and $\psi$, for every $\tau_0\in [0,t]$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that 
$$\|T_\tau \psi-T_{\tau_0}\phi\|\le 1\quad \text{whenever }\ |\tau-\tau_0|<\delta  \text{ and } \|\psi-\phi\|<\delta  \tag1$$
Using the compactness of the interval $[0,t]$, we can cover it by finitely many intervals $(\tau_i-\delta_i  ,\tau_i+\delta_i)$ of the above nature. Now let 
$$M=1+\max_i \|T_{\tau_i}\phi\|,\quad r=\min_i \delta_i \tag2$$
It follows that $\|T_\tau \psi\|\le M$ whenever $\|\psi-\phi\|<r$ and $\tau\in [0,t]$.

The same argument yields a uniform bound for $f(T_\tau \psi)$ in some neighborhood of $\phi$: you only need to replace (1) with 
$$|f(T_\tau \psi)-f(T_{\tau_0}\phi)|\le 1\quad \text{whenever }\ |\tau-\tau_0|<\delta  \text{ and } \|\psi-\phi\|<\delta  \tag{3}$$
Then take the intersection of the two neighborhoods of $\phi$.